# How to set a value in completionHandler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, uitableview

I had a problem regarding how can I set my NSArray in completionHandler block. I successfully assign a value for NSArray in my completion block, but once I tried to NSLog NSArray value outside completion block it gave 0.

Here is my full code.

```
//
//  HomeTVC.m
//  ABOX
//
//  Created by Zero on 11/18/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Zero. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomeTVC.h"
#import "facebook.h"

@interface HomeTVC ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *userPageLikesParams;
    NSArray *pagesInfo;
    facebook *fb;
}
@end

@implementation HomeTVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    fb = [[facebook alloc] init];

    userPageLikesParams = @{@"fields": @"about,name,created_time",@"limit": @"5"} ;
    [fb getUserPagelikes:userPageLikesParams completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *pagesResult) {

        pagesInfo = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        pagesInfo = pagesResult[@"data"];

        // NSArray *p = pagesResult[@"data"];
        // [self pages:p];
    }];
}

//- (void)pages:(NSArray*)pageInfo {
//    
//    self.pagesInfo = pageInfo;
//    NSLog(@"fb pages result ayam : %@", self.pagesInfo[0]);
//    NSLog(@"array counzz : %d", (int)self.pagesInfo.count);
//}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 // here I got 0, how can I solve this problem?
    NSLog(@"table count : %d", (int)pagesInfo.count);
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that you are logging Array after the completion block has been completed

Comment: Why are you creating an empty array and then throwing it out in the very next statement?

Comment: check by declaring __block NSArray *pagesInfo;  instead of NSArray *pagesInfo;

Comment: Just reload your tableview inside the "getUserPagelikes" block when the pages info array have values

Comment: thank you all, now it's working perfect as I want.  duhhh because of silly mistake I waste my time for 3 hours. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @michal, you should reload your tableView below like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  fb = [[facebook alloc] init];
  userPageLikesParams = @{@"fields": @"about,name,created_time",@"limit": @"5"} ;
  [fb getUserPagelikes:userPageLikesParams completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *pagesResult) 
  {
    pagesInfo = pagesResult[@"data"];
    [yourTableViewObj reloadData];
    // NSArray *p = pagesResult[@"data"];
    // [self pages:p];
  }];
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: he does not need the "`pagesInfo = [[NSArray alloc] init];`" line, because it gets re-written / reset on the very next line.

Answer (score 2):

Reload your table view when the completion block finishes up and you should see your `pagesInfo` array populated and returning a count.

Comment: You never have to nil check before returning the count of an array.  If the array reference is nil, the return of `[array count]` is zero.